# Problem with NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS (mapstruct 1.3.1)

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

After upgrading mapstruct from 1.2.0 to 1.3.1 I noticed that the annotation `@Mapper(nullValueCheckStrategy=NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)` in not in effect.
Is it a bug of new mapstruct version?

Example:

The code below:

```
String id = getTestId( testId);
if ( id != null ) {
    testCase.setTestCaseId( id );
}
else {
   testCase.setTestCaseId( null );
}
```

while the right is:

```
String id = getTestId( testId);
if ( id != null ) {
   testCase.setTestCaseId( id );
}
```

Comment: How does your mapping method look like? Is this an update mapping?

Comment: I find the solution here: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1790

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour has been made more consequent with the advent of `NullValuePropertyMapping`. I think that was mentioned in the release notes as well. Checkout the documentation:

1: update methods (`@MappingTarget`)
https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-result-for-null-properties

2: regular (non update) methods
https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#checking-source-property-for-null-arguments